# issue with $_POST and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a MySQL DB from where i next to extract data based on user search.

I have no problem displaying the post variable like this :

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST)) {
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);      
echo "Results  - " . $name ."\n";
}

$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

$conn->close();
?>
```

The error -

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file.

As soon as I add a MySQL connection, without even any query to be done, I get a parse error. Why is that ?

I have tried adding a specific query as I need the results displayed.

I have also tried using a different from of submitting, still no luck, getting same parse error.

Comment: Add complete code. Then only we can see whats wrong.

Comment: <?php 
    
    if (isset($_POST)) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);      
    echo "Results  - " . $name ."\n";
    }
    
    
    $servername = "localhost";     
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "test";
    
    
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,     $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    
    
    $conn->close();
    
    
   ?>






error getting : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Comment: Add full code and add the error as well

Comment: Re-posting the code in a comment doesn't really help. What is the parse error you get? And post the code (in your post, not in a comment) that fails, not the one that works.

Comment: You're missing a } for the last if statement

Comment: You are not closing `}` of if condition.

Comment: "Here is some generic code. Also, my site has an error somewhere else. Help me". Sorry, I don't mean to mock, I just wish to emphasize how unhelpful this question is. Please provide the error and the code that triggers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a syntax error.

```
if ($conn->connect_error) { 
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 

} <--- u have missed this

$conn->close();
```

Final code

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST)) {
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);      
echo "Results  - " . $name ."\n";
}

$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "test";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

}    <-------    this is missing in your code.

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: ok...that was embarrassing, it's pretty much always the obvious :)  thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad it helped you:)